# postgresql UPDATE and RETURNING query not returning latest value

Tags: postgresql, select

I have the following table

```
  p_id, j_id, completed
    a     b     false  
    c     b     true
```

and am using the following query to update the `complete` to `true`

```
    update progress_status set completed = true  where p_id = 'c' returning (
        select to_json(t) from (select count(*) as total, sum(case when "completed" = true then 1 else 0 end) as completed from progress_status where j_id='b') t
    ) as status
```

but the query always returns the pre existing value before the update query was executed.
In the above case I would get `completed` as `1` and `total` as `2` whereas I expected it to be
`completed = 2 total = 2`

What is the reason behind this and how can I avoid such a response? Also is there a performance benefit to executing these two queries in the same query or it doesn't really make a difference in performance ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH updated AS (UPDATE ... RETURNING list of columns)
SELECT your select query FROM updated;
```

This should make the SELECT operate on what the UPDATE returns, not on the table itself.

Comment: hi, what would inserted be in this case ? Is it a keyword or the table ?

Comment: it's a mistake, I meant to refer to CTE named "updated" and I wrote "inserted" instead ;) Note you can pick any name for the CTE, "updated" isn't a special keyword.